# Adding LineBreak in List-item XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, line-breaks, xsl-fo

Can someone tell me how I can add a break between the item-label and the body.
So first I want the firstname on a line. then a line with nothing and then the name John on a new line:
this is the code I have tried a lot but nothing works:
I am unsing Apache FOP to turn mij XSL into PDF

```
<fo:list-item>
  <fo:list-item-label><fo:block>FirstName:</fo:block></fo:list-item-label>
  <fo:list-item-body><fo:block>John</fo:block></fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, list-item is designed for placing elements side-by-side, not above each other. 
Anyway, you don't need the list-item at all. Just create 2 blocks with the information you need, and they'll be placed one above the other automatically.

Specify space-after on the first block to get the empty line:

```
<fo:block space-after="12pt">
```

Comment: I Need list-item is the best way to fix the lay out like I want but seems like it isnt possible to add a break tried everything I find it very strange!

Comment: I tried what you told me and i Can use block can you give me example how to add a break after block?

Comment: fixed, it's space-after instead of space-below.